# How can a contract confirm the off-chain sorting

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Suppose a mapping of addresses and their respective balances. I would like to recover a list of the top "k" addresses by balance.

I understand that sorting inside the contract is prohibited especially when the number of addresses is arbitrary large. I have found that the proposed way is to observe for events emitted on state changes and then sort the data off-chain.

However I can't see how this sorting can be trusted. The data could be manipulated by a malicious node or by the the front-end.
Ideally the contract should be able to confirm that the sorted data provided correspond to the top "k" balances before using them for any other operation.

How would you go about this? To me it seems you cannot alleviate this need for trust on the off-chain sorting without doing some on-chain sorting. Even confirming that the data are sorted doesn't mean they truly are the desired top "k".

Comment: Potentially relevant: [the oracle problem](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/oracles/#oracle-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Verifying the elements are sorted correctly on-chain should be O(N) on the number of elements.

Another option is to include rewards and punishments in the protocol when a wrong answer is submitted.

Comment: Indeed checking if they are sorted should be relatively cheap. But knowing if the submitted list is the top "k" elements in the mapping should require that the contract knows the max. Unfortunately I can't see a way of doing that programmatically without sorting inside the contract.